# SQL-Join with NULL-columns

Tags: sql, join, null

I'm having the following tables:

Table a

| Field | Type | Null | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bid | int(10) unsigned | YES |  |
| cid | int(10) unsigned | YES |  |

Table b

| Field | Type | Null |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bid | int(10) unsigned | NO |
| cid | int(10) unsigned | NO |
| data | int(10) unsigned | NO |

When I want to select all rows from b where there's a corresponding bid/cid-pair in a, I simply use a natural join `SELECT b.* FROM b NATURAL JOIN a;` and everything is fine.

When `a.bid` or `a.cid` is `NULL`, I want to get every row where the other column matches, *e.g.* if `a.bid` is `NULL`, I want every row where `a.cid = b.cid`, if both are `NULL` I want every column from `b`.

My naive solution was this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
FROM b
JOIN a ON (ISNULL(a.bid) OR a.bid=b.bid ) AND (ISNULL(a.cid) OR a.cid=b.cid)
```

Is there any better way to to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's pretty much it.

(I'd generally rephrase `ISNULL(a.bind)` as `a.bind IS NULL` for ANSI SQL compliance FWIW.)

Answer (score 14):

The ISNULL function is not actually ANSI compliant. Yes, you do need to check for nulls in both columns. Another way to write your query would be:

```
Select Distinct b.*
From b
    Join a
        On ( a.bid = b.bid Or ( a.bid Is Null And b.bid Is Null ) )
            And ( a.cid = b.cid Or ( a.cid Is Null And b.cid Is Null ) )
```

Yet another way that avoids the use of Distinct:

```
Select b.*
From b
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From a
                Where  ( a.bid = b.bid Or ( a.bid Is Null And b.bid Is Null ) )
                    And ( a.cid = b.cid Or ( a.cid Is Null And b.cid Is Null ) )
                )
```

Comment: b.bid and b.cid can't be Null, so the extra test is unnecessary, but I like the second example without distinct.

Comment: @tstenner - Ah. Missed that you stated the columns in b as being not-nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Too old, but here is my 2 cents, it might be useful for someone:

```
ISNULL(a.cid, 0) = ISNULL(b.cid) AND ISNULL(a.bid, 0) = ISNULL(b.bid)
```